# find factors of numbers between 2 and 100

Tags: java, for-loop

I tried to get the factors of numbers from 2 to 100 in `Java`.

```
    boolean bSqrt = true;
    int sqrt;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");

        sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(i);
        for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt; j++) {
            if ((i % j) == 0) {
                if(j != sqrt)
                    System.out.print(j + " ");
                if (j != (i / j))
                    System.out.print(i / j + " ");
                if (bSqrt & sqrt != (i / j) & sqrt != j & ((i % sqrt) == 0)) {
                    System.out.print(sqrt + " ");
                    bSqrt = false;
                }
            }
        }
        bSqrt = true;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

but this code couldn't get the right answer for 4, 6, 8, 25 etc. This is probably because it iterates sqrt of `i` and also because the condition 'if(j != sqrt)' (this is because factor `j` can sometimes equal to sqrt of `i`, the sqrt is certainly a factor of `i`, that will be printed later in the code). So I am wondering how to fix the code and maybe improve the code to give the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You need to understand the maths behind the sqrt optimization; i.e. the mathematical justification for not iterating to 100 in the inner loop.  (It is simple ...)

Once you understand that, look at what your code is *actually* doing at that point ... and compare it with what your (new?) mathematical understanding says you *should* be doing.